# Nextjs 13 - Getting URL from SSR Layout

Tags: next.js

I'm having trouble to find out how to see which url was used to access my NextJS project with. It's some kind of multitenancy project I am working on an my goal is to be able to distinguish wether you visited the site from URL A or URL B.

So the issue is that I am using the /app/ directory and that seems to be having some issues with this. I like the /app/ structure and would like to keep it if possible. But when I try and access anything with the router or getServerSideProps, I get an error like this:

```
"getServerSideProps" is not supported in app/.
```

Or when using router:

```
You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.
```

And yeah, I do understand the errors, but I just cant wrap my head around on how to get the visited URL inside of my layout.tsx. Maybe that is totally impossible and im just trying to do something which isnt possible.

I would LOVE to keep everything SSR if possible.

Does anyhere know a trick? Thanks

Comment: Please provide code example